# why is on_pre_enter or on_enter ignored in kivy if you write more than one

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

imports:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
```

```
kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    TextInput:
        id: t1
    TextInput:
        id: t2
    TextInput:
        id: t3
    TextInput:
        id: t4

'''
```

`MyApp` class:

```
class MyApp(App):
    text = StringProperty('-.text')

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)



    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.ids['t1'].text = "textinput1"



    def on_enter(self):
        self.ids['t2'].text = "textinput2"


    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.ids['t3'].text = "textinput3"



    def on_enter(self):
        self.ids['t4'].text = "textinput4"




if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with Kivy, it's simply how Python works that writing a second method with the same name replaces the previous definition.

Comment: there is no method that I can write more than one